# react redux, thunk fulfilled event happens prematurely

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I have used a similar Thunk and slice in other areas of my project and all work as expected but this particular one does not work, the difference with this Thunk is it contains an axios call that waits for the result so that it can be chained the next axios call.

After logging i think the issue is that the Thunk is firing 'fulfilled' after the first axios call and not waiting for the full function to complete, this one has me stumped on how to fix this issue.

```
export const getPlanAPI = createAsyncThunk('dataStorePlans/plan', async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('/api/routes')
    let promises = [];
    const routeData = [];

    // I think the Thunk is firing 'fulfilled' at this point.

    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            promises.push(axios.get('/api/routedetail?planid=' + response.data[i].id + '&jobcount=' + response.data[i].jobs))
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
        results.forEach(function (response) {
            routeData.push(response.data[0]);
        })

        return routeData
    });

});
```

```
export const planSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'dataStorePlans/plan',
    initialState: {
        planList: [],
        status: ''
    },
    reducers: {
        getPlanState: (state) => {
            return state
        }
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [getPlanAPI.pending]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'Loading';
        },
        [getPlanAPI.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'Success';
            state.planList = action.payload
        },
        [getPlanAPI.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'failed';
            action.error = action.error.message;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: try `await Promise.all` or `return Promise.all`

Comment: Fantastic ```return Promise.all``` worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that your Function will not wait for the Promises to be finished. It also did never return the `routeData`.

You also clutter your function with lots of iterations and pushing stuff around. It is easy to forget where you have to return things. I know `async` is the new hot stuff, but a promise chain works better here. Even if I keep your structure the function becomes way easier to read if you use `map` at the right places.

```
export const getPlanAPI = createAsyncThunk('dataStorePlans/plan', async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('/api/routes')
    let promises = [];

    try {
        promises = response.data.map(({id, jobs}) =>
            axios.get(`/api/routedetail?planid=${ id }&jobcount=${ jobs }`)
        )
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    return Promise
        .all(promises)
        .then(results =>
            results.map(response => response.data[0])
        )
});
```